Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/be/account to localhost:8081 [ENOTFOUND]
I'm trying to do an http request from an Ionic project with Angular. To avoid a CORS exception I have created a proxy.conf.json file:
{
  "/local": {
    "target": "localhost:8081",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
       "^/local": ""
    }
  }
}

I have created a service with an http request:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public saveAccount(
    account: Account
  ): Observable<AccountResponse> {
    return this.http.post<AccountResponse>(
      '/local/account',
      {
        names: account.names,
        lastName: account.lastName,
        email: account.email,
        phone: account.phone,
        password: account.password,
        birthDate: account.birthDate
      },
    );
  }
}

Also I added this in angular.json file:
"architect": {
    ...
    "serve": {
       ...
       "options": {
           "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
       },
       ...
    }
    ...
}

but when the http request is ejecuted this error is showed:

I'm sure that this route is correct becuase I tested it with postman:

I don't know if I am forgeting something. I am using this versions:

ionic 7.2.0
angular 18.0.4
spring boot 3.3.1


should be "/local": {...pathRewrite: {'^/local' : ''}}. otherwise resulting url includes the local word :8081/local/accounts

@Andrei I just added it but I still have the same problem.

did you restart your dev server after  this update?

yes I did, I made the modification and then I restarted the server

it seems target should be fixed http://localhost:8081

yes, that was the problem. Also, in the service, I wrote "/account" insted of "/accounts. Thank you @Andrei
